# how to get the callstack symbol names from cocoa crash report

Tags: cocoa, crash, report

When I get a crash report, it doesn't show me the function that caused the crash as it used to. This is from an OSX desktop app.

```
2   com.myCompany                   0x000000010018d565 0x100156000 + 226661
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88de220c __invoking___ + 140
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either fiddle with [`symbolicatecrash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports), or use the command-line tool [`atos`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/atos/) (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/68507)).

I've had much better success with the latter. In both cases you need the original binary that created the crash report and its associated .dSYM file if the symbols aren't included in the binary.

Comment: I've been using symbolicatecrash with the dsym and doesn't seem to do anything to the file.   ./symbolicatecrash -A -v myApp.crash "MyApp.app.dSYM"     Is that the command you use?

Comment: Yeah, symbolicatecrash uses a bunch of poorly documented heuristics in an attempt to find the symbols and gives up fairly easily. I would try following the instructions in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/68507

Comment: I am going to try it thanks. You have had success using atos with desktop apps?

Comment: I've mostly used it for iOS apps, but I really don't see why it wouldn't work for desktop applications, the tool has been around since 1998.